# Select2.js setting the default value to select box with array of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I wanted to set a default value to the select2 box

here is the data I am using

```
var countries = [
    // Africa
    "Algeria",
    "Angola",
    "Benin",
    "Botswana",
    "Burkina Faso",
    "Burundi",
    "Cabo Verde",
    "Cameroon",
    "Cape Verde",
    "Central African Republic",
    "Chad",
    "Comoros",
    "Congo",
    "Cote d'Ivoire",
    "Djibouti",
    "Egypt",
    "Equatorial Guinea",
    "Eritrea",
    "Ethiopia",
    "Gabon",
    "Gambia",
    "Ghana",
    "Guinea",
    "Guinea-Bissau",
    "Ivory Coast",
    "Kenya",
    "Lesotho",
    "Liberia",
    "Libya",
    "Madagascar",
    "Malawi",
    "Mali",
    "Mauritania",
    "Mauritius",
    "Morocco",
    "Mozambique",
    "Namibia",
    "Niger",
    "Nigeria",
    "Rwanda",
    "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "Senegal",
    "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone",
    "Somalia",
    "South Africa",
    "South Sudan",
    "Sudan",
    "Swaziland",
    "Tanzania",
    "Togo",
    "Tunisia",
    "Uganda",
    "Zambia",
    "Zimbabwe",
    // Asia
    "Afghanistan",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Bhutan",
    "Brunei",
    "Cambodia",
    "China",
    "Timor-Leste",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Israel",
    "Japan",
    "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "North Korea",
    "Kuwait",
    "Kyrgyzstan",
    "Laos",
    "Lebanon",
    "Malaysia",
    "Maldives",
    "Mongolia",
    "Myanmar (Burma)",
    "Nepal",
    "Oman",
    "Pakistan",
    "Palestine",
    "Philippines",
    "Qatar",
    "Russia",
    "Saudi Arabia",
    "Singapore",
    "South Korea",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "Syria",
    "Taiwan",
    "Tajikistan",
    "Thailand",
    "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "dot Emirates",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vietnam",
    "Yemen",
    // Europe
    "Albania",
    "Andorra",
    "Armenia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Croatia",
    "Cyprus",
    "Czech Republic",
    "Denmark",
    "Estonia",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "Georgia",
    "Germany",
    "Greece",
    "Hungary",
    "Iceland",
    "Ireland",
    "Italy",
    "Kosovo",
    "Latvia",
    "Liechtenstein",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Macedonia",
    "Malta",
    "Moldova",
    "Monaco",
    "Montenegro",
    "Netherlands",
    "Norway",
    "Poland",
    "Portugal",
    "Romania",
    "San Marino",
    "Serbia",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Spain",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Kingdom (UK)",
    "Vatican City (Holy See)",
    // North America
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Bahamas",
    "Barbados",
    "Belize",
    "Canada",
    "Costa Rica",
    "Cuba",
    "Dominica",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "El Salvador",
    "Grenada",
    "Guatemala",
    "Haiti",
    "Honduras",
    "Jamaica",
    "Mexico",
    "Nicaragua",
    "Panama",
    "St. Kitts and Nevis",
    "St. Lucia",
    "St. Vincent and The Grenadines",
    "Trinidad and Tobago",
    "United States of America (USA)",
    // Oceania
    "Australia",
    "Fiji",
    "Kiribati",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Micronesia",
    "Nauru",
    "New Zealand",
    "Palau",
    "Papua New Guinea",
    "Samoa",
    "Solomon Islands",
    "Tonga",
    "Tuvalu",
    "Vanuatu",
    // South America
    "Argentina",
    "Bolivia",
    "Brazil",
    "Chile",
    "Colombia",
    "Ecuador",
    "Guyana",
    "Paraguay",
    "Peru",
    "Suriname",
    "Uruguay",
    "Venezuela"
];
```

and I am trying to do like below

```
$("#nationality").select2({
     data:countries,
}).select2("val", $('#nationalityvalue').val());
```

it is not working. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
$("#nationality").select2({
   data:countries,
});
$("#nationality").val($('#nationalityvalue').val()).trigger("change");
```

Please check working snippet below :

```js
var countries = [
    // Africa
    "Algeria",
    "Angola",
    "Benin",
    "Botswana",
    "Burkina Faso",
    "Burundi",
    "Cabo Verde",
    "Cameroon",
    "Cape Verde",
    "Central African Republic",
    "Chad",
    "Comoros",
    "Congo",
    "Cote d'Ivoire",
    "Djibouti",
    "Egypt",
    "Equatorial Guinea",
    "Eritrea",
    "Ethiopia",
    "Gabon",
    "Gambia",
    "Ghana",
    "Guinea",
    "Guinea-Bissau",
    "Ivory Coast",
    "Kenya",
    "Lesotho",
    "Liberia",
    "Libya",
    "Madagascar",
    "Malawi",
    "Mali",
    "Mauritania",
    "Mauritius",
    "Morocco",
    "Mozambique",
    "Namibia",
    "Niger",
    "Nigeria",
    "Rwanda",
    "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "Senegal",
    "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone",
    "Somalia",
    "South Africa",
    "South Sudan",
    "Sudan",
    "Swaziland",
    "Tanzania",
    "Togo",
    "Tunisia",
    "Uganda",
    "Zambia",
    "Zimbabwe",
    // Asia
    "Afghanistan",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Bhutan",
    "Brunei",
    "Cambodia",
    "China",
    "Timor-Leste",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Israel",
    "Japan",
    "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "North Korea",
    "Kuwait",
    "Kyrgyzstan",
    "Laos",
    "Lebanon",
    "Malaysia",
    "Maldives",
    "Mongolia",
    "Myanmar (Burma)",
    "Nepal",
    "Oman",
    "Pakistan",
    "Palestine",
    "Philippines",
    "Qatar",
    "Russia",
    "Saudi Arabia",
    "Singapore",
    "South Korea",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "Syria",
    "Taiwan",
    "Tajikistan",
    "Thailand",
    "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "dot Emirates",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vietnam",
    "Yemen",
    // Europe
    "Albania",
    "Andorra",
    "Armenia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Croatia",
    "Cyprus",
    "Czech Republic",
    "Denmark",
    "Estonia",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "Georgia",
    "Germany",
    "Greece",
    "Hungary",
    "Iceland",
    "Ireland",
    "Italy",
    "Kosovo",
    "Latvia",
    "Liechtenstein",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Macedonia",
    "Malta",
    "Moldova",
    "Monaco",
    "Montenegro",
    "Netherlands",
    "Norway",
    "Poland",
    "Portugal",
    "Romania",
    "San Marino",
    "Serbia",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Spain",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Kingdom (UK)",
    "Vatican City (Holy See)",
    // North America
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Bahamas",
    "Barbados",
    "Belize",
    "Canada",
    "Costa Rica",
    "Cuba",
    "Dominica",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "El Salvador",
    "Grenada",
    "Guatemala",
    "Haiti",
    "Honduras",
    "Jamaica",
    "Mexico",
    "Nicaragua",
    "Panama",
    "St. Kitts and Nevis",
    "St. Lucia",
    "St. Vincent and The Grenadines",
    "Trinidad and Tobago",
    "United States of America (USA)",
    // Oceania
    "Australia",
    "Fiji",
    "Kiribati",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Micronesia",
    "Nauru",
    "New Zealand",
    "Palau",
    "Papua New Guinea",
    "Samoa",
    "Solomon Islands",
    "Tonga",
    "Tuvalu",
    "Vanuatu",
    // South America
    "Argentina",
    "Bolivia",
    "Brazil",
    "Chile",
    "Colombia",
    "Ecuador",
    "Guyana",
    "Paraguay",
    "Peru",
    "Suriname",
    "Uruguay",
    "Venezuela"
];
$("#nationality").select2({
  data: countries
});
$("#nationality").val($('#nationalityvalue').val()).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="nationality"></select>

<input type="text" id="nationalityvalue" value="Guyana"/>
```